# Inject EJB into domain object with Java EE 6

Tags: jakarta-ee, domain-driven-design, ejb, java-ee-6, cdi

How can I inject an EJB into a domain object (an JPA entity) with Java EE 6?

Answer (score 11):

In Java EE 6, CDI extends the concept of managed component to anything and EJB can be injected into a CDI managed bean (using the `@Inject` annotation). But while interaction between JPA and CDI has been considered, this has not been made part of the Java EE 6 specification(s). In other words, injection into a JPA entity is not possible.

#### See also

- [CDI injection broken between POJOs](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=396170)

Answer (score 4):

EJB3 client injection applies to "managed classes" such as Servlets and EJBs (and JSF page code etc).

The JPA objects are not, I believe, managed in this sense. So I think you would be back to pre-EJB3 techniques, doing JNDI lookup etc.

However as has been observed there may  be some tangle in your hierarchy of responsibilities if you need to do this. It would be interesting if you posted a question about your overall design so that we could think about the design issues. My default position is that EJBs use JPA domain objects, JPA objects don't use EJBs.

Comment: Looks like you're right: beans are managed (instantiated) by the container. http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/intro.html#bean-definition I want to avoid JNDI lookups because of coupling. I'd prefer to inject the LoginAttemptRepository manually in the UserRepository.

Injecting services into domain classes is not so uncommon with domain driven design, if I'm not totally wrong. I have a user object, which I want to ask about failed logins in the last x seconds. The login attempts are stored in a repository because this information is needed separate from a specific user.

Comment: In Java EE 6, the concept of "managed classes" is not limited to Servlet, EJBs, etc with CDI. There is no interaction between CDI and JPA though.

Answer (score 1):

You would typically not do this simply because domain objects come out of the database as opposed to the container and therefore injecting services isn't as straight forward.

This does not mean however that you should not do this.

You know what your system is meant to achieve and which other systems it interacts with. This knowledge will effect the decision I'd imagine.

See [Active Record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) link.  As I meanted in my comment *typically* small systems would choose this route.