# EJB3.1 - possible to start @EJB injection chain without JNDI lookup?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ejb-3.0, seam, ejb-3.1

I am using EJB3.1 deployed to JBoss AS 5.1, so I'm using the @EJB injection. It works great when called from another EJB. Like this bean:

```
@Stateless (mappedName = "daos/MyDao")
public class MyDAO implements MyDaoRemote {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myEm")
private EntityManager em;
```

which is injected into this other bean

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "handler/MyHandler")
public class MyHandler implements MyHandlerRemote {

@EJB(mappedName = "daos/MyDao")
private MyDaoRemote myDao;
```

However, my application starts from a POJO. I don't think you can use the @EJB injection outside of a EJB... SO, is it possible to get MyHandler without using a JNDI lookup?  This code works:

```
return (MyHandlerRemote) new InitialContext().lookup("handler/MyHandler");
```

but I would love to avoid doing this lookup.  In Seam and Spring, it seems like the scanning of classes for annotations is easier.

I probably don't NEED @EJB injection, but I like having the container manage the PersistenceContext for me, and the auto-wiring.

Seems like Weld could help, but I don't think it will work in JBoss AS 5.1, as could Spring, but it seems like there should be a starting point for EJB without JNDI lookups.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMO, whatever you are trying to achieve is not possible without CDI.

Comment: Try this: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021370/ejb-3-1-ejb-injection-into-pojo>

Comment: bummer... only JSR-299 implementation I know of are Weld and Guice, seems like a fair bit of weight to solve a pretty basic problem.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but what's up with all those `mappedName` attributes?

Comment: Arjan, I'm changing the JNDI lookup name. Probably don't need it on the DAO anymore. The default JNDI in JBoss included project structure like "MyEar1.0/MyJar1.0/MyHandler", which I don't want to include in my lookup...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Seam](http://seamframework.org/) for injecting EJBs in POJOs running under JBoss AS 5.1, without the need for making a JNDI lookup - instead, using Seam's `@In` annotation.

Comment: I'm familiar with Seam, and I agree it would work.  I suppose since Seam used a version of Weld before it went JSR, it's pretty similar.  Since I don't think the problem can truly be solved, this is as good as we can do.