# How to debug a call to an EJB from a Netbeans platform module

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, netbeans-platform

Using GlassFish 3.1.2, I try to call a Session Bean from a Netbeans platform module, and I get a null pointer exception. My problem is that I have no trace explaining how / where the NPE is generated.

The code in my Module is simply:

```
import ejb.MySessionRemote;
import javax.ejb.EJB;

public class TestServer {

    @EJB
    private static MySessionRemote mySession;

    public boolean execute() {
        System.out.println("result = " + mySession.getString()); //NPE here: mySession is null
        return true;
    }
}
```

The Session bean "My Session", the remote interface and the application deployed on the server side are just the ones from this tutorial: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html

Any help greatly appreciated.

Note: I've checked [this tutorial](http://netbeans.dzone.com/nb-call-ejb-on-glassfish), without solving my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `mySession` is null, it was probably not injected. You can inject into **managed** beans (EJBs for example), because these instances are managed (created/removed) by a **container**, and the container does the injection for you.

You can possibly inject into a POJO, if you use [CDI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3483720/2390083).

If `TestServer` is part of a stand-alone application for example, try to lookup the EJB using **JNDI**. This is what your [tutorial](http://netbeans.dzone.com/nb-call-ejb-on-glassfish) does as well. It involves setting up the properties to get an `InitialContext`, and the lookup of the EJB using JNDI.