# EJB, can't get injection in Json response method

Tags: java, ejb

I have a problem with my EJB:

```
public class EntryResponseBuilder extends BaseResponseBuilder {
@EJB
private ApplicationCustomerCache applicationCustomerCache; //null
```

I have something like this in class that returns a JSON response.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class ApplicationCustomerCache {
    @EJB
    CustomerDao customerDao;
    private Map<Integer, Customer> customerMap;
    private Map<Integer, List<Customer>> applicationToCustomersMap;
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationCustomerCache.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        try {
            get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("ApplicationCustomerCache.init()", e);
        }
    }

    private void get() throws SQLException {
```

And its working fine, except that when I try to get injection in `EntryResponseBuilder`, it's empty. One function before, it inject, where I have class with `@Stateless`. I've searched in Google, but I can not find any solution.

Comment: Can you show where you inject EntryResponseBuilder please ?

Comment: i don't do that i guess i have problem right there, that this class is not manage by contener

Comment: Indeed, that may be your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dealing with two issues here:

1. Your're trying to inject an instance of a bean on a POJO, which is not managed by the container;
2. What's the EJB spec that you're following?

For both of them, I think the following answers can help you:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3483720/1346996
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8138452/1346996

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using `InitialContext()`

```
ApplicationCustomerCache applicationCustomerCache = (ApplicationCustomerCache) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/ApplicationCustomerCache");
```